# Parsing broken XML

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse some third-party XML which has a number of what I believe are "illegal" features

- multiple root elements
- "anonymous" close tags
- comments containing --
- mismatched start and end tags

Example

```
<foo>
  <toto>123</>  <!-- == "anonymous" close tag -->
  <tata>
     <titi>456</>
  </>     <!-- == "anonymous" close tag-->
</foo>
<bar>   <!-- == multiple root elements -->
</bar>
```

Is this some variant of XML I've not heard of? Everything I've found so far including [Well-formedness and error-handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling) suggests that this is not XML.

> Tag names are case-sensitive; the start-tag and end-tag must match exactly.
>
> A single root element contains all the other elements.

I'm just wondering what simplest way of parsing this in Java without having to resort to regex. I was considering intial parse to correct to XML so I can then use XPath or other standard mechanisms.

Comment: At first glance, I would say that you would need to use a parser to handle this problem in general.  The easiest solution might be to go back to the source and ask for cleaner XML data.

Comment: My advice, don't use regex. Bad news is, you will probably need to figure out and build your own parser based on the documents you have, unless there is one available for that bizarre idiom.

Comment: The anonymous close tags are a problem - are you sure there is exactly one for each opening tag? Otherwise, there is no way to parse this.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes always matching close tag, although some tags in same file are closed correctly. i.e. <foo>123</foo>

Comment: Well then, my first option would be to try to talk to the "3rd party" and beat them up about their format. Second option would be, indeed, to write a pre-parser for this. Can't give a full answer, as I would first look for any "shortcuts", like knowing that no tags have attributes, that there are no CDATA sections, that all special characters are properly escaped etc.

Comment: JSoup's [`parseXmlFragment`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#parseXmlFragment-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) gives a very close result to what you want, but interprets the `<toto>` empty end tag differently (it actually ignores it and ends `<toto>` after the end of `<tata>`)

Comment: During the development of XML in 1997-8, there was a proposal to allow minimized close tags like <a>...</>. The syntax was accepted by a beta release of the Microsoft XML parser, but they quickly withdrew support for it when the 1.0 standard was ratified in 1998. It's allowed in SGML, so you may find you can parse this document using an SGML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to fix this was to tokenize the whole input and rebuild it piece by piece filtering out the problems, closing tags properly etc.

Additionally I fixed the multiple root tags issue by wrapping the whole content with new element root, i.e. `<root>${content}</root>`

```
public class BrokenXmlParser {

    public String parse(InputStream resource) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        List<String> tokens = tokenize(builder.toString());
        return correct(tokens);
    }

    private String correct(List<String> tokens) {
        StringBuilder reassemble = new StringBuilder();
        reassemble.append("<root>");
        Deque<String> tagNameStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        boolean skip = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
            String token = tokens.get(i);
            if ("<".equals(token)) {
                tagNameStack.push(tokens.get(i + 1));
            }
            if ("<?".equals(token) || "<!".equals(token)) {
                // skip comments
                skip = true;
            } else if ("<".equals(token)) {
                skip = false;
            }
            if ("</>".equals(token)) {
                reassemble.append("</" + tagNameStack.pop() + ">");
            } else if ("</".equals(token)) {
                // sometimes tags are incorrectly closed
                reassemble.append("</" + tagNameStack.pop() + ">");
                i = i + 2;
            } else if (!skip) {
                reassemble.append(token);
            }
        }
        reassemble.append("</root>");
        return reassemble.toString();
    }

    private List<String> tokenize(String input) {
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern tag = Pattern.compile("(</>|<!|<\\?|\\?>|</|<|>|\\s+|[^<> ]+)");
        Matcher matcher = tag.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            tokens.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return tokens;

    }

}
```